# Language tags in article content

Tags: articles, tags, language, com-content

I have a Joomla site with lots of articles and two languages.
All content is the same, except for the weekdays.

Is it possible, in any way, to use the Joomla override language to create tags and add them to the articles?

This way I could use one article for both languages.

The content is similar to this

```
 __________________________
| Monday | tuesday | ...
|--------------------------
|10:00   | 9:00    | ...
|9:00    | 10:00   | ...
|...     | ...     |
```

The main reason for this is that the articles contain bus fares and if there is any change we need to change on both languages.

I'm also open to other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this language plugin:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easy-language

Once installed in your article you can do:

{lang en}Monday{/lang}{lang es}Lunes{/lang}

It will display the text on the selected languaje.

Hope it work for you

Comment: Wonderfull.. :)

Comment: thanks, but the credit if for the developer of this terrific idea :)